# std::bad_array_new_length

Tags: c++, сортировка, динамические-массивы

Пишу код пирамидальной сортировки динамического массива на с++. Сам не очень разбираюсь, писал код основываясь на лекциях.
Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void heapify(long long arr[], long long n, int i) {
    int largest = i;

    int l = 2 * i + 1;
    int r = 2 * i + 2;


    if (l < n && arr[l] > arr[largest])
        largest = l;


    if (r < n && arr[r] > arr[largest])
        largest = r;


    if (largest != i) {
        swap(arr[i], arr[largest]);
        heapify(arr, n, largest);
    }
}


void heapSort(long long arr[], long long n) {
    for (long long i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(arr, n, i);


    for (long long i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);
        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }
}


void printArray(long long arr[], long long n) {
    for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
}

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    long long* arr, n;
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    arr = new long long[n];

    for (long long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%lld", &arr[i]);
    }

    heapSort(arr, n);

    printArray(arr, n);
}
```

При запуске выдает ошибку:

Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFED34206BC в D.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::bad_array_new_length по адресу памяти 0x0000001AADF3F8D0.

Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FFED34206BC в D.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::bad_array_new_length по адресу памяти 0x0000001AADF3F8D0.

В чем проблема?

Comment: `scanf` не прочитал значение из входного потока. В переменной `n` остался мусор. Работу `scanf` вы не проверяете. Весь остальной код в вопросе не нужен.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Как оказалось, не проверил входные данные - первым шло отрицательное число. Исправил, всё заработало.